# Swtiching between menu resource files in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android

Is it possible to switch between `menu` resource files for a `NavigationDrawer`? I am using `SharedPreferences` to store the data about the user, and I would like to implement a different `menu` for a logged user, different from the `menu` that's supposed to apper if the user is not logged. 
This is how I use the `Navigation Drawer`at the start of the activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

I am aiming at something like:

```
 if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
        ...
        //Set the logged menu resource file
 }
 else{
        //Set the normal menu resource file 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via [inflateMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#inflateMenu(int))

```
 int menu = R.menu.user_menu;
 if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
     //Set the logged menu resource file
     menu = R.menu.loggedin;
 }
 navigationView.inflateMenu(menu);
```

**Note**: Existing items in the menu will not be modified or removed

Comment: This works like a charm. I added in the `.xml` of the `NavigationDrawer` file an empty `menu` as `app:menu="@menu/menu"` resource file, so when I inflate the one needed, won't overlap over existing items. Any chance you could advise me about how to separate the items in groups? For example, 3 items, separated from other 2 by a horizontal line?

Comment: Nevermind, I just made a simple mistake. Forgot to add an `ID` to the `group` so the line did not appear.